# Joda Time decimal conversion and rounding

Tags: time, jodatime

Is there a way in `Joda time` where-in the difference between two days (Period)
can be rounded off (up or down) to nearest day.

E.g.: 7 days and 15 hrs should be rounded to 8 days while 7days and 8 hours should be rounded off to 7 days.

I tried looking into PeriodFormatterBuilder, however it has methods which returns hours but nothing to round off (like ceil or floor).

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Comment: Sorry for late late reply but i tried and worked for me

Comment: Then could you apply my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no method in Jodatime for your case.

I wrote something like this, I hope it helps you;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        getDiffer(new DateTime().plusDays(2), new DateTime().plusDays(4).plusHours(13));
        getDiffer(new DateTime().plusDays(2), new DateTime().plusDays(4).plusHours(8));
    }

private static void getDiffer(DateTime date1, DateTime date2) {
    Period p = new Period(date1, date2);
    int days = p.getDays();
    int hours = p.getHours();
    if (hours < 12)
        System.out.println("Days = " + days);
    else
        System.out.println("Days = " + (days + 1));
}
```

And the result is;

```
Days = 3
Days = 2
```